# SwiftUI side padding in a HStack when resizing

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, padding

Xcode:

[image]

Me:

[image]

As you can see from the images I have to imitate how Xcode does.

The result I get is what you see in the second image.

I tried using `Spacer()` inside `HStack`, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Can you give me a hand?

```swift
                      VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Name")
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                                TextField("", text: $inspectorModel.fileName)
                                    .font(.system(size: 11))
                                    .onSubmit {
                                        changeFileName(newFileName: inspectorModel.fileName)
                                    }
                            }

                            HStack {
                                Text("Type")
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                                fileType
                            }

                            Divider()
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Spacer()` is not working because the `TextField` is expanding as much as it can. To remedy the problem you have to manually calculate the `padding` & offset the `Text`.

Comment: How can I calculate it?

Comment: Keep adding the padding value until you get what you need.

Comment: I'd rather find a way that works in general, without doing any calculations for each element.

Comment: I added spacer().padding, and it works on iPhone

Comment: Exactky my point, `.padding()` is adding a `padding` regardless if it's for the `Spacer` or the `Text`. By default, it's in the `TextField`'s nature to expand as much as it can because it doesn't have a width.

Answer (score 0):

Using this `Spacer().padding()` may help

```
      VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            HStack {
                Spacer().padding()
                Text("Name")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                TextField("", text: $inspectorModel.fileName)
                    .font(.system(size: 11))
                    .onSubmit {
                        changeFileName(newFileName: inspectorModel.fileName)
                    }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Type")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                fileType
            }
            
            Divider()
        }
```

Comment: It does not work.
The problem is this:
I have a field of type TextField and Picker, which should take up all the space available to them, therefore full width.
As you can see from the image me, normally the two types of fields have different sizes, even in full width.

Comment: @Paul how about `Spacer(minLength: X)`?